# What is the binary representation of a boolean value in c#

Tags: c#, binary, bit, boolean, representation

I know that a boolean value is 1 byte (8 bits long)
But I would like to know is what is its binary representation.
e.g. 
decimal     => binary
4           => 100 (0000 0100)
8           => 1000 (0000 1000)
bool value  => ???

Comment: I can't think of a scenario (other than some interop where you are forced to) where it's a good idea to treat booleans as integers.

Comment: You can use BitArray if you wanted to interrogate the binary values. You cannot use watch, but you can use .Get[x] to get each bits value (true - 1, false - 0). You can also use Convert.ToByte() to convert the bool type to byte.

Comment: @gooch: `Convert.ToByte(bool)` just does the equivalent of `return (byte)(value ? 1 : 0);` so doesn't actually prove anything about the underlying representation. It just so happens that the underlying representation is the same.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The BitArray can be used for interrogation. The ToByte was more than emm was asking.

Comment: @gooch: Using `BitArray` doesn't prove anything about the underlying representation of `bool` either. `BitArray` uses the individual bits of an `int[]` array to store it's values, and the `Get` method then does the equivalent of `return (requiredBitOfRequiredArrayElement == 1);`.

Answer (score 20):

`bool` is a built-in basic type in C#. Any underlying representation would be an implementation detail.

The *C# 4.0 Language Specification* states in section 4.1.8:

> The `bool` type represents boolean logical quantities. The possible values of type `bool` are `true` and `false`.
>
> No standard conversions exist between `bool` and other types. In particular, the `bool` type is distinct and separate from the integral types, and a `bool` value cannot be used in place of an integral value, and vice versa.
>
> In the C and C++ languages, a zero integral or floating-point value, or a null pointer can be converted to the boolean value `false`, and a non-zero integral or floating-point value, or a non-null pointer can be converted to the boolean value `true`. In C#, such conversions are accomplished by explicitly comparing an integral or floating-point value to zero, or by explicitly comparing an object reference to null.

If we take this one level deeper and see how the corresponding type is specied in the *Common Intermediate language* (CIL) we will see that a CLI Boolean type occupies 1 byte in memory. The *Common Language Infrastructure* (CLI) specification says in Partition III, section 1.1.2:

> A CLI Boolean type occupies 1 byte in memory. A bit pattern of all zeroes denotes a value of false. A bit
>   pattern with any one or more bits set (analogous to a non-zero integer) denotes a value of true.

However, this is specified on another level and from within C# you should not have to care; even if a future version of the CLI specification might change the representation of the boolean type, or if the C# compiler decided to map a `bool` in C# to something different, your C# code would still have the same semantics.

Comment: built-in basic type of .NET, actually. C# `bool` is just shorthand for .NET `System.Boolean`

Comment: @Anthony Pegram: True, but as the question was specific to C# I only refered to the C# spec.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a quick bit of code that demonstrates the underlying representation of `bool`, *on the current platform wherever it happens to be running*:

```
var x = new NotAGoodIdea();

x.TheBool = true;
Console.WriteLine(x.TheByte);    // 1

x.TheBool = false;
Console.WriteLine(x.TheByte);    // 0

// ...

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct NotAGoodIdea
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public bool TheBool;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte TheByte;
}
```

(Note that although `1` appears to represent `true` and `0` appears to represent `false`, this is just an implementation detail. You shouldn't rely on this detail, or assume that it will remain consistent across different versions and/or implementations, or even that the current platform always uses the same consistent representation.)

**EDIT...**

The [ECMA CLI spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) (partition III, section 1.1.2) is pretty clear about the allowable representations of the `Boolean` type:

> **1.1.2 Boolean data type**
>
> A CLI Boolean type occupies 1 byte in
>   memory. A bit pattern of all zeroes
>   denotes a value of false. A bit
>   pattern with any one or more bits set
>   (analogous to a non-zero integer)
>   denotes a value of true.

It appears that the current Microsoft CLR adheres to the ECMA spec in allowing multiple representations of `true`. The following example displays a single "False" line (for `0`) followed by 255 lines of "True":

```
// re-use the NotAGoodIdea struct from the previous example
var x = new NotAGoodIdea();

for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++ )
{
    x.TheByte = (byte)i;
    Console.WriteLine(x.TheBool);
}
```

Comment: Note though that `object.Equals()` doesn't consider two `bool` that are internally different as equal. Arguably a bug with `object.Equals()` and certainly unlikely to come up with sane code, but there is at least that one case where while the CLI spec considers something true, the BCL does not.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not contradicting 0xA3's answer, but if you use:

```
BitConverter.GetBytes(true);
BitConverter.GetBytes(false);
```

You'll get a byte array of `{ 1 }` and `{ 0 }`. In other words, the binary values would be `00000001` and `00000000`.

This doesn't mean that's how .NET handles booleans in memory - it's just how it converts them to byte arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all languages/environments (not only .NET) implement `true` as equivalent to the integral value 1, and `false` equal to 0.<sup>1)</sup>

However, there’s one important exception, namely VB6, which had `true` equal to –1. This made quite a few things difficult for the migration to .NET, because the loose type system of VB6 allowed to mix integers and booleans in the same expression, and `2 And True` meant something else in VB6 than in VB.NET.

---

<sup>1)</sup> Although many systems allow an implicit conversion of any numeric value unequal to 0 to `true` in a boolean context. Some (especially dynamic) languages even go further, and say that all objects except for special objects (e.g. `None`, empty array, the list goes on …) equal `true`.

Comment: In older system, -1 (0xffffff) and 0 are also used.

Comment: I thought that C treated 0 as false, and anything else as true?

Comment: @Oded: yes, true == ! false. Same for conversions form pointer.

Comment: @Oded: yes, that’s why I wrote “implement” instead of “treats”, and if you write `true` in C++ (`TRUE` in C? Dunno …) this will be implemented by the value `1`. – but notice the added remark.

Answer (score 1):

Typically `Boolean` values are represented by `false` being all zeros and `true` being anything else.  For simplicity this is normally -1 (all bits on of a signed integral type) due to [Two's Complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).