# Update [bool / int] parameter in C#, read in fortran [ NOK / OK]

Tags: c#, fortran, interop

I have a fortran subroutine that I call from C# and want to be able to terminate. This I can do using an integer variable that I alter in C# as the fortran routine runs. However changing this to a `bool` / `logical(c_bool)` does not work. (In the code below is also an option where I change a value in a callback function.)

Working code (with `int` parameters)
C#:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

Console.WriteLine("C# starting");
var cb = new Natives.ActionRefInt(OnUpdateProgress);
var terminate = 0;
var t = Task.Run(() => Natives.TestCallBackAndVariable(cb, ref terminate));
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    await Task.Delay(900);
    terminate = i * 100;
    Console.WriteLine($"C# loop i = {i}, terminate = {terminate}");
}
terminate = -1;
await t;


static void OnUpdateProgress(ref int val2)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"C# OnUpdateProgress received val2 = {val2}");
    val2 += 10;
    Console.WriteLine($"C# OnUpdateProgress setting val2 = {val2}");
}
public static class Natives
{

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate void ActionRefInt(ref int progress);

    [DllImport(dllName: "FortranLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void TestCallBackAndVariable(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] ActionRefInt callBack,
    ref int terminate);
}
```

Fortran:

```
subroutine TestCallBackAndVariable(callBack, terminate)
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT::TestCallBackAndVariable
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DECORATE,ALIAS:"TestCallBackAndVariable" :: TestCallBackAndVariable
use ISO_C_BINDING
implicit none
! Variables
external                        ::  callBack
integer(C_INT),intent(inout)   ::  terminate
integer(C_INT)                  ::  ii
integer(C_INT)                  ::  val2
! Body of TestCallBackAndVariable
write(*,*) "Starting TestCallBackAndVariable in fortran lib"
do ii = 1,10
    call sleep(1)
    val2 = ii
    call callBack(val2)
    write(*,*) "Fortran loop ii = ",ii,", and terminate = ", terminate, ", and val from callback = ", val2
    if (terminate<0) exit
end do
write(*,*) "Finished TestCallBackAndVariable in fortran lib"
end subroutine TestCallBackAndVariable
```

Not working as expected code (with `bool` / `logical`)
C#:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

Console.WriteLine("C# starting");
var cb = new Natives.ActionRefBool(OnUpdateProgress);
var terminate = false;
var t = Task.Run(() => Natives.TestCallBackAndVariable(cb, ref terminate));
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    await Task.Delay(900);
   
    Console.WriteLine($"C# loop i = {i}, terminate = {terminate}");
}
terminate = true;
await t;


static void OnUpdateProgress(ref bool val2)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"C# OnUpdateProgress received val2 = {val2}");
    val2 = true;
    Console.WriteLine($"C# OnUpdateProgress setting val2 = {val2}");
}

public static class Natives
{

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate void ActionRefBool(ref bool progress);

    [DllImport(dllName: "FortranLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void TestCallBackAndVariable(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] ActionRefBool callBack,
    ref bool terminate);
}
```

Fortran:

```
subroutine TestCallBackAndVariable(callBack, terminate)
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT::TestCallBackAndVariable
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DECORATE,ALIAS:"TestCallBackAndVariable" :: TestCallBackAndVariable
use ISO_C_BINDING
implicit none
! Variables
external                        ::  callBack
logical(C_BOOL),intent(inout)   ::  terminate
integer(C_INT)                  ::  ii
logical(C_BOOL)                 ::  val2
! Body of TestCallBackAndVariable
write(*,*) "Starting TestCallBackAndVariable in fortran lib"
do ii = 1,10
    call sleep(1)
    val2 = .false.
    call callBack(val2)
    write(*,*) "Fortran loop ii = ",ii,", and terminate = ", terminate, ", and val from callback = ", val2
    if (terminate) exit
end do

write(*,*) "Finished TestCallBackAndVariable in fortran lib"
end subroutine TestCallBackAndVariable
subroutine TestArray(i,j,arr)
```

In the bool/logical variant does not c# modify value of the logical `terminate` fortran variable. However, changing the logical value in the `OnUpdateProgress` does work. (propagates back to fortran)

Help on this is, as always, much appreciated.

(VS 2022 NET 6, IFORT 2021.6.0 64bit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Fortran, the `logical(kind=c_bool)` type maps to the C `_Bool` type of the companion C processor (=compiler).

In C, `_Bool` is defined to be an unsigned integer type (size is implementation dependent but typically one byte) however with only two allowable values, 0 for false and 1 for true (0 and 1 here meaning the unsigned integer bit patterns that represent the integer values 0 and 1). Any other bit pattern is a trap representation and invokes undefined behavior.

However, in C# the internal representation of Bool variables is, per the ECMA CLI spec ( [What is the binary representation of a boolean value in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335841/what-is-the-binary-representation-of-a-boolean-value-in-c-sharp) ), 0 for false, and all other bit patterns (that is, with any of the bits set to 1) are true.

Thus, AFAICT, the Fortran `logical(c_bool)` and the C# `bool` type are NOT interoperable, and you need some other mechanism to transfer boolean values between Fortran and C#. E.g. transferring them as integers.